# Python pip Modules not found by Python 3.9 " No module named '...' "

Tags: python, installation, pip, path

Recently I installed Python 3.9 and I did NOT mark “Add Python 3.9 to PATH” because I was not aware of the effect. Uninstalling & reinstalling with marking the checkbox has no effect.
My problem is Python 3.9 does not find installed pip modules which are located at:
c:\users\USER\virtualenv\scripts
My question is; how could I indicate the new version of Python, where to find installed pip modules?

I also tried to add a new entry to the Environment Variables as described on following tutorial:
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

In my case I put:
Path
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39; C:\Users\USER\VirtualEnv\Scripts

Python 3.9 still shows:

> > > import openpyxl
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
> > > import selenium
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I hope I explained well enough and you could help me… Thanks to everybody!